# Check for each row in several columns and append for each row if the requirement is met or not. python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

I have the following example of my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_date': ['01-07-2017', '01-07-2017', '01-08-2017'], 
                   'end_date': ['01-08-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-08-2017'],
                   'second_date': ['01-09-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-07-2017'], 
                   'cust_num': [1, 2, 1],
                   'Title': ['philips', 'samsung', 'philips']})
```

1. If the `cus_num` is equal in the column
2. The `Title` is equal for both rows in the dataframe
3. The `second_date` in a row <= `end_date` in an other row

If all these requirements are met the value `True` should be appended to a new column in the original row. 
Because I'm working with a big dataset I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. 
In this case only the first record should get a true value.

I have checked for the `apply` with `lambda` and `groupby` function in python but couldnt find a way to make these work.

Comment: Clarification: when you say equal, do you expect `'Philips'=='philips'` to return True? Because it will not

Comment: How is the original row determined within your DataFrame?

Comment: Im sorry, in the original dataframe the title names are equal.
The original dataframe is from a .csv file it exists out of +/- 40 columns.

Comment: Is there ever a case where a particular `cust_num` would have two unique `Title` values that each have a match? For example, `cust_num` of 3 corresponds to 4 rows, where 2 rows have 'sally' in Title and 2 rows have 'jim'?

Comment: Yes this is possible, each row has a subscription based article. Each row has a start, end date etc. The cust_num is an unique customer number, this customer can have different titles during the same time frame.

Comment: Sorry for having to post this in a comment, but what is your expected output for the following dataframe (please post as edit to your question): `df = pd.DataFrame({'first_date': ['01-07-2017', '01-07-2017', '01-08-2017', '01-07-2017', '01-08-2017'], 
                   'end_date': ['01-08-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-08-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-08-2017'],
                   'second_date': ['01-09-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-07-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-07-2017'], 
                   'cust_num': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
                   'Title': ['philips', 'samsung', 'jim', 'jim', 'philips']})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (spontaneously I cannot come up with a faster method):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["second_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["second_date"], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df["end_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"], format='%d-%m-%Y')

df["new col"] = False

for cust in set(df["cust_num"]):
indices = df.index[df["cust_num"] == cust].tolist()
if len(indices) > 1:
    sub_df = df.loc[indices]
    for title in set(df.loc[indices]["Title"]):            
        indices_title = sub_df.index[sub_df["Title"] == title]
        if len(indices_title) > 1:            
            for i in indices_title:
                if sub_df.loc[indices_title]["second_date"][i] <= sub_df.loc[indices_title]["end_date"][i]:
                    df["new col"] = True
                    break

df["new_col"] = new_col
```

First you need to make all date columns comparable with eachother by casting them into datetime. Then create the additional column you want.

Now create a set of all unique customer numbers and iterate through them. For each customer number get a list of all row indices with this customer number. If this list is longer than 1, then you have several same customer numbers. Then you create a sub df of your dataframe with all rows with the same customer number. Then iterate through the set of all titles. For each title check if there is the same title somewhere else in the sub df (len > 1). If this is the case, then iterate through all rows and write `True` in your additional column in the same row where the date condition is met for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

This should work. Also while reading comments, I am assuming that all cust_num is unique.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'first_date': ['01-07-2017', '01-07-2017', '01-08-2017'], 
               'end_date': ['01-08-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-08-2017'],
               'second_date': ['01-09-2017', '01-08-2017', '15-07-2017'], 
               'cust_num': [1, 2, 1],
               'Title': ['philips', 'samsung', 'philips']})

df["second_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["second_date"])
df["end_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"])

df['Value'] = False

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if (i != j):
            if (df.loc[j,'end_date'] >= df.loc[i,'second_date']) == True:
                if (df.loc[i,'cust_num'] == df.loc[j,'cust_num']) == True:
                    if (df.loc[i,'Title'] == df.loc[j,'Title']) == True:
                        df.loc[i,'Value'] = True
```

Tell me if this code works! and any errors.

Comment: but you only want the entries where the title matches right?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do only want it where the title matches.
I get the following error at the "if (df.loc[j,'end_date'] >= df.loc[i,'second_date']) == True:" line. 
:KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

Comment: is this error with the df that you provided? If not, did you have a different index for the df?

Comment: This is an error with my own df, I have it working now, Thank you!
I will be able to look tomorrow in to more detail in the output

Comment: This code will not give the desired result. It will put a `True` in each line where all conditions are met, but as far as I understand @Vincent he wants to have only a `True` at the first occurence for the same cust_num and Title, but not for all.

Comment: Well, I checked your code again and found an other mistake: `if (df.loc[j,'end_date'] >= df.loc[i,'second_date']) == True:` will only compare strings if you not cast it into datetime object. Hence your code will say that `15-08-2017 >= 01-09-2017` is `True`, as `"15" > "01"` is `True`. Maybe you should at least consider casting the columns to datetime.

Comment: I guess, I went towards what I saw a quick good solution. I am just waiting to reach 50 as I have to comment on an important post related to my research. Apologies